# ASP.NET WebApi 2 HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage null

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a **ASP.NET WebApi 2** application. I added **Swashbuckle** to it (Swagger for .NET). I run the application and navigate to localhost:8000/swagger. That request has a StatusCode of **301** and redirects me to localhost:8000/swagger/ui/index. That request has a StatusCode of **200**, but **HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage** is null. I want to log where the request is coming from so I want to log **HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri**.

Why is the RequestMessage null? Is it because the previous request is a redirect? Is there any other way of getting the RequestUri?

Comment: `/swagger/ui/index` is not on an `ApiController`, it's a normal  web `Controller`, isn't it?

Comment: Because if it is, you need to look at `Request.Url` or `Request.RawUrl`.

Comment: Yes... I think so. The only thing is that the web controller's response is of type HttpResponseMessage so I can't go Response.Url or Response.RawUrl. The only thing I can do is HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx. If I can't do it that's fine. Just wondering - is the RequestMessage null because it is a normal web controller, which is just loading a html page?

Comment: Hmm, now I'm not sure if we're looking at the same library versions, it's confusing. Could you clarify what nuget packages versions are you using?

Comment: Could the confusion be that I am talking about a response and you are talking about a request? (btw I can do Request.RequestUri). Nuget packages - newest Web Api 2 packages; System.Net.Http - version 4.

Comment: Well I'm stumped as to why you want to read the request url from the response message...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78512/discussion-between-skolima-and-marta).